# How to keep the same scene portion in view during resize?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview

I am using `QGraphicsView` to show something like function graphs. `QGraphicsView` keeps its transformation during resize, so the visible portion of the scene changes.

I need to keep the view exactly the same during resize - aspect ratio don't have to be kept since I allow independent scaling on X and Y axes.

This does not work:

```
void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override
{
    QRectF rect = mapToScene(this->viewport()->rect()).boundingRect();
    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
    fitInView(rect);
}
```

Problem is in getting the proper view rectangle. This solution zooms out on resize.

Is there some simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. You will need to `scale` the view manually when its size changes, and restore the old center point. In python:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    w_ratio = self.rect().width() / event.oldSize().width()
    h_ratio = self.rect().height() / event.oldSize().height()
    self.scale(w_ratio, h_ratio)

    self.centerOn(self.old_center)
```

You obviously need to set `self.old_center` earlier, e.g. in `showEvent()`. If the view can be translated by the user you will also need to update `self.old_center` in `mouseReleaseEvent()`.

```
def showEvent(self, event):
    self.old_center = self.mapToScene(self.rect().center())

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    super(MyView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    self.old_center = self.mapToScene(self.rect().center())
```

Answer (score 0):

What about keeping the scene rectangle visualized by this view in the view with `fitInView`?

```
void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override
{
    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
    fitInView(this->sceneRect());
}
```

Comment: I believe that will make the full scene visible as opposed to keeping the currently displayed portion of the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is quite old, but I came across the same challenge and found a solution that worked well.

I think the issue is that within the resize event, the viewport coords (mapped to the scene) are being fetched. In this case, the viewport has already changed (and thus the displayed scene), then `fitInView` is called with some slightly updated scene coordinates and so the display scene actually changes. This turns into a cascade like effect.

What we want to do is always pass the *same* scene rect to `fitInView` during the resize event. I was able to accomplish this by locally storing the scene coords when I first load the image and then anytime the displayed scene changes (pan/zoom/reset view, etc). Then when the resize event is called, we're always passing the same scene coordinates and don't getting caught in that change loop.